# Is it legal to >>> 0 in order to keep bitwise operations as unsigned 32-bit?

Tags: javascript

For example, this is `-1` a.k.a. `0xFFFFFFFF` as a signed 32-bit:

```
0xFFFFF000 | 0xFFF
```

However, this is this is `4294967295` a.k.a. `0xFFFFFFFF` as an unsigned 32-bit:

```
(0xFFFFF000 | 0xFFF) >>> 0
```

Can I rely on using this `>>> 0` trick to keep my bitwise operations as unsigned 32-bit?

Nothing in the spec[1] indicates that this should fail, and it seems to work fine in a few simple tests...

[1] https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-unsigned-right-shift-operator

Comment: "*Nothing in the spec indicates that this should fail*" - in contrast, it indicates that this should work! Indeed, this is the standard way to cast something to uint32.

Comment: Ah - and you're right, it is a duplicate, whups!

Comment: One that is admittedly hard to find :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E%3E_(Zero-fill_right_shift)) (emphasis mine):

> This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Zero bits are shifted in from the left. **The sign bit becomes 0, so the result is always non-negative.  Unlike the other bitwise operators, zero-fill right shift returns an unsigned 32-bit integer**.

So it sounds like you can count on that always working.

Also from the [ECMAScript specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-unsigned-right-shift-operator) Section 12.9.5.1 #8 (again emphasis is mine):

> Return the result of performing a zero-filling right shift of lnum by shiftCount bits. Vacated bits are filled with zero. **The result is an unsigned 32-bit integer**.